# Jupyter notebook output window hidden

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So this sounds like a bad joke.

I got a script running in a notebook that was printing to the output as it was executing. Now our cat jumped on the laptop and suddenly the output window dissapeared.

I can see the cell is still executing as the aterisk is still showing but the ouput window has dissapeared.

How can I make it re appear again?

Comment: Have you tried just restarting the kernel?

Comment: @lizard_heart I am guessing I will loose the progress that script has made if I do so.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Hopefully somebody will be able to help you. I'm not too familiar with Jupyter notebooks but I'm sure there's a way to show that cell.